# I am consuming jwt token from Asp.Net MVC using httpclient should I store jwt in session["token"] or should I store it in cookie on client device

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jwt, httpclient

Where should the token be saved on the server side session or stored in the cookie as the client browser? I am using `HttpClient` to consume and not ajax.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question and adding more details ? In order for anyone to help you more details about your context are needed.

Comment: I am consuming api from mvc web application using httpclient it return toke 
which I have to used for subsequent request.Should I store the return token in some session variable on mvc controller or it should be stored in cookie on client side which one is best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If the JWT token that you negotiate with the token server is client specific (e.g.: an access token for an OIDC client using the client credentials flow) you can safely store it in a cache (it can be a server side memory cache or any sort of distributed cache). There is no need to save it in the authentication cookie of the user.

If the JWT token is, instead, user specific (e.g.: a JWT access token that a user get during an interactive login flow, such as the OIDC hybrid flow for an MVC application) the best approach is saving it as part of the user authentication cookie. This is much better than saving it inside the server side session, because you avoid server side affinity and your system will be stateless and capable of scalign much better.

So, to summarize:

- save client specific access tokens in a server side cache (e.g: memory cache or a distributed cache shared between instances of your server application)
- save user specific access tokens in the user authentication cookie. Avoid any server side session state, so that you get a steteless service and you avoid server affinity bound for the logged in user